# Random.sample outputs a 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

I am using a two dimensional array(a deck) and I am trying to random.sample to fill another list with 5 random items. Though, i get a 3 dimensional list and I cannot fix it

Any help?

```
import random
suits =['H', 'D', 'S', 'C']
numbers = []
deck = []
for i in range(0, 13):
 numbers.append(i+2)
for i in range(len(suits)):
 for j in range(len(numbers)):
    deck.append([numbers[j], suits[i]])
player1 = []
pc = []
for i in range(5):
 player1.append(random.sample(deck, 1))
 pc.append(random.sample(deck, 1))
 print(player1,pc)
```

Output:[[[14, 'C']], [[11, 'D']], [[6, 'C']], [[14, 'S']], [[13, 'H']]] [[[2, 'C']], [[6, 'D']], [[11, 'C']], [[6, 'D']], [[9, 'S']]]... I Just cannot get rid of the extra list that's created(I need to use .sample and not .choice which worked fine before)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `random.sample(deck, 1)` return a 2D array, that's what is causing the problem, you can fix these two lines:

```
player1.append(random.sample(deck, 1)[0])
pc.append(random.sample(deck, 1)[0])
```

**Check error**

```
random.sample(deck,1)
[[6, 'D']]
```

Comment: Yeah, you were correct.. I have stayed up all night after some drinks and decided to finish a uni project at this time and i just couldn't be bothered to get to a solution. Thank you a lot man!

Comment: no worries, keep going. do upvote & accept the solution it it helps:)